# что нужно установить что бы программировать на C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, разработка-игр

Я решил установить Visual studio 2020 community и возник вопрос: где поставить галочки для разработки на c#. Знаю что можно позже установить оставшийся контент, так что скажите все, что связано с c# (софт,геймдев)

Comment: Десктопная разработка .NET + Кросс-платформенная разработка .NET. Этого хватит для начала, остальное можете оставить как стоит. Состав установленных пакетов можно изменить в любое время и после установки. Если нужен Unity для игр, добавьте еще его. (кстати, Visual Studio 2020 не существует)

Comment: @aepot: https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ja/vs/preview/vs2022/ думаю ТС имел ввиду это.

Answer (score 2):

Для разработки на C# необходимо установить пакет "Разработка классических приложений .NET". Для его установки вы должны установить [установщик Visual Stusio 2019 Community](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/ru/vs/) и открыть скачавшийся .exe файл, после чего установятся необходимые файлы установщика. Запустится Visual Studio Installer. Там много различных Рабочих Нагрузок, но для разработки на C# необходимо выбрать пункт "Разработка классических приложений .NET", для разработки на Unity с помощью C# необходимо установить "Разработка игр с помощью Unity", и для Веб-разработки необходимо установить "ASP.NET и разработка веб-приложений", после чего нажать кнопку "Установить".

Comment: поставил плюс за развернутый ответ) Не забудь через два дня поставить себе галочку на этот ответ. Добро пожаловать на стек оверфлоу и удачи в начинаниях!